# Working around Duplicate association path bug in Nhibernate with Query Over

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, queryover

I've got a bit of code that tries to access same association path twice and they're really same aliases but because I'm using query objects, I have them in two different places and I am not really sure how to get the alias.

May be some code can clear the confusion:

```
var privateBlogQuery = new BlogQuery()
    .ByUser(1)
    .RemoveHidden()
    .FetchUserDetails();


//<-------- In Blog Query object class: ------>

/// Gets all the private blogs the user has permissions to view
public BlogQuery ByUser(int userId)
{
    var authorisedUsers = null;

    this.Left.JoinQueryOver(r => r.AuthorisedUsers, () => authorisedUsers)
        .Where(r => r.User.Id == userId);

    return this;
}

/// Removes all private blogs user has marked to be hidden
public BlogQuery RemoveHidden()
{
    var authorisedUsers = null;

    this.Left.JoinQueryOver(r => r.AuthorisedUsers, () => authorisedUsers)
        .Where(r => !r.IsHidden);

    return this;
}

/// Loads up details of all users who have permission 
/// to view the private blog
public BlogQuery FetchUserDetails()
{
    var users = null;
    var authorisedUsers = null;

    this.Left.JoinQueryOver(r => r.AuthorisedUsers, () => authorisedUsers)
        .Left.JoinQueryOver(r => r.User, () => users);

    return this;
}
```

There are times when I'm using all 3 criteria individually and the sql generated is precisely what I need and everything is nice and dandy as long as they are used separately.

Now I need to use them all together, at the same time and nhibernate throws an exception `duplicate alias` and I changed up the alias on these three functions but then I am greeted with the `duplicate association path` exeception.

A bit of googling and I [learnt that it is a bug in hibernate](http://blog.dezfowler.com/2008/06/duplicate-association-path-bug-in.html) and I also found a few [workarounds on this bug](http://blog.amdaris.com/nhiberante-2-1-workaround-with-duplicate-alias-or-duplicate-association-path/)

Trouble is I am using Query objects and hence Query over and I am not really sure how to get the association path / alias here.

So how do I go about this please?

Comment: This is a very specific workaround and may not apply to your situation, but I was able to get around this when I ran into it by mapping my table to a schema-bound view that did the joins for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- make `authorisedUsers` a membervariable of `BlogQuery` and use a marker/flag to know if `ByUser` and `RemoveHidden` should do the Join
- use `JoinAlias`

example

```
AuthorisedUser authorisedUser;
bool authorisedUsersJoined;

public BlogQuery RemoveHidden()
{
    if (!authorisedUsersJoined)
        this.Left.JoinAlias(r => r.AuthorisedUsers, () => authorisedUser);

    this.Where(() => !authorisedUser.IsHidden);

    return this;
}
```

FetchUserDetails is mutual exclusive with the other two because filtering on an association prevents NH from initializing the association. You'll need to subquery with the filter and query the resulting Ids and initialize then.

```
/// Loads up details of all users who have permission 
/// to view the private blog
public BlogQuery FetchUserDetails()
{

    this.Query = QueryOver.Of<Blog>()
        .WhereRestrictionOn(b => b.Id).IsIn(this.Query.Select(b => b.Id))
        .Fetch(r => r.AuthorisedUsers).Eager
            .ThenFetch(au => au.User).Eager;

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Hi - How would I get / set the ``.Where(() => !authorisedUser.IsHidden);`` when ``authorisedUsersJoined`` is true? Because I need to set that condition anyway, I need to know whether a join has already been performed..

Comment: i fixed the code. The where condition should always be set regardless of the condition